# Set default value in drop down menu in Thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have a table that has a column "Shoe", which is a dropdown menu
[image]

I want to set a default value for my dropdown in Thymeleaf

```
<option th:each="shoe : ${shoes}" th:selected="${shoe == item.getShoe()}" th:value="${shoe}" th:text="${shoe}"></option>
```

In the instance when item.getShoe() == '', I'd like for the default option for the dropdown menu to be just that, '', so it appears as blank on the dropdown menu.

Instead, whenever item.getShoe() == '', it is choosing the first value from the shoes list, NIKE, to be the default option for the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a blank `<option></option>` before your `th:each`.

```
<select ...>
  <option></option>
  <option th:each="shoe : ${shoes}" th:selected="${shoe == item.getShoe()}" th:value="${shoe}" th:text="${shoe}"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I wasted hours on this.